php executing systemctl command - selinux problem
I am trying to restart wireguard service from php script, like this:
<?php
exec("sudo systemctl restart wg-quick@wg0", $output, $retval);
?>

Exec doesn´t work. $output is empty, $retval is 4. I switched domain httpd_t to permissive mode with command command semanage permissive -a httpd_t , then exec works, service wireguard is succesfully restarted, $retval is 0. Here is part from audit.log when httpd_t is permissive (I greped only line with 'denied'):
type=USER_AVC msg=audit(1729701110.392:226691): pid=1246 uid=81 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='avc:  denied  { send_msg } for msgtype=method_return dest=:1.271885 spid=1258 tpid=115666 scontext=system_u:system_r:systemd_logind_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=dbus permissive=0  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=81 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'UID="dbus" AUID="unset" SAUID="dbus"

I had mode 'denied' problems, but I solved them with commands
setsebool -P httpd_mod_auth_pam 1
setsebool -P httpd_setrlimit 1

but I am unable to correct the last error above..
I am using AlmaLinux 8.1
Thank you for help.

So it's been said -- from a security perspective, semanage permissive -a httpd_t is a very bad idea. You'd be much better off letting your PHP code write requests to a message bus (in a restrictive format -- think an enumerated list of pre-vetted, known-safe operations, not arbitrary shell commands), and then have defensively-written software already running as a sufficiently-privileged user (so no sudo is needed) pulling requests off the bus and enacting them.

Running https permissive could be Okay just for the sake of limited test. Never keep it that way for too long a time and never on a production machine.
That being said, if you don't want to go through the message-bus solution, which sounds the more elegant to me, you may want to write your own SELinux policy module to allow httpd_t to transition, via sudo, to a brand new SELinux type/domain of your own, something named like php_wg_restarter_t. And you allow this new type/domain of yours to perform just the legitimate set of operations on the wigeguard service(s).
Need that be, you may want to create a specific SELinux type for said wireguard service(s).
